# isEmpty' isn't a function or method and can't be invoked. > >

Tags: flutter

> > > lib/screens/edit_producrscreen.dart:89:39: Error: 'isEmpty' isn't a
> > > > > function or method and can't be invoked.
> > > > >                     if (value!.isEmpty()) {
> > > > >                                       ^^^^^^... lib/screens/edit_producrscreen.dart:112:39: Error: 'isEmpty' isn't a
> > > > > function or method and can't be invoked.
> > > > >
> > > > >                     if (value!.isEmpty()) {
> > > > >                                       ^^^^^^... lib/screens/edit_producrscreen.dart:139:39: Error: 'isEmpty' isn't a
> > > > > function or method and can't be invoked.
> > > > >
> > > > >                     if (value!.isEmpty()) {
> > > > >                                       ^^^^^^... lib/screens/edit_producrscreen.dart:160:52: Error: 'isEmpty' isn't a
> > > > > function or method and can't be invoked.
> > > > >                       child: _imageUrl.text.isEmpty()
> > > > >                                                    ^^^... lib/screens/edit_producrscreen.dart:183:45: Error: 'isEmpty' isn't a
> > > > > function or method and can't be invoked.\
> > > >
> > > >
> > > > I get these type of errors

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shopdapp/provider/product.dart';
import 'package:shopdapp/provider/products.dart';

class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const EditProductScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const routeName = '/edit-product';
  @override
  _EditProductScreenState createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
  final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _describtionFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _imageUrl = TextEditingController();
  final _imageurlFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var _editedProduct =
      Product(id: '', title: '', description: '', price: 0, imageUrl: '');

  @override
  void initState() {
    _imageurlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose() {
    _imageurlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
    _imageurlFocusNode.dispose();
    _priceFocusNode.dispose();
    _describtionFocusNode.dispose();
    _imageUrl.dispose();

    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateImageUrl() {
    if (!_imageurlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
      if (!_imageUrl.text.startsWith("https") ||
          (!_imageUrl.text.endsWith("jpeg") &&
              !_imageUrl.text.endsWith("png") &&
              !_imageUrl.text.endsWith("jpg"))) {
        return;
      }

      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _submitForm() {
    final isvalid = _form.currentState!.validate();
    if (!isvalid) {
      return;
    }
    _form.currentState!.save();
    Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: false).addProduct(_editedProduct);
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Edit the Products"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _submitForm();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.save))
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Form(
            key: _form,
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: " Tile"),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
                  },
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty()) {
                      return " Provide the tile";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _editedProduct = Product(
                        id: _editedProduct.id,
                        title: value.toString(),
                        description: _editedProduct.description,
                        price: _editedProduct.price,
                        imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: " Price"),
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_describtionFocusNode);
                  },
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty()) {
                      return "Enter the Valid Price";
                    }
                    if (double.tryParse(value) != null) {
                      return "Enter the  price";
                    }
                    if (double.tryParse(value)! <= 0) {
                      return "Enter the valid price greater than zerpo";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _editedProduct = Product(
                        id: _editedProduct.id,
                        title: _editedProduct.title,
                        description: _editedProduct.description,
                        price: double.parse(value!),
                        imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl);
                  },
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: " Describtions"),
                  // textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  maxLines: 3,
                  focusNode: _describtionFocusNode,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value!.isEmpty()) {
                      return "Plese Enter the describtions";
                    }
                    if (value.length < 10) {
                      return "Please enter the describtion atlese min 10 characters";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) {
                    _editedProduct = Product(
                        id: _editedProduct.id,
                        title: _editedProduct.title,
                        description: value.toString(),
                        price: _editedProduct.price,
                        imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl);
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: _imageUrl.text.isEmpty()
                          ? Text("Enter UrL")
                          : FittedBox(
                              child: Image.network(_imageUrl.text),
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 8),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.green)),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Image URL"),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                        focusNode: _imageurlFocusNode,
                        controller: _imageUrl,
                        onEditingComplete: () {
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value!.isEmpty()) {
                            return "Plese Enter the URL adress";
                          }

                          if (!value.startsWith("https")) {
                            return "Enter the Valid URL adress";
                          }

                          if (!value.endsWith("jpeg") &&
                              !value.endsWith("png") &&
                              !value.endsWith("jpg")) {
                            return "Enter the Valid URL adress";
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          _editedProduct = Product(
                              id: _editedProduct.id,
                              title: _editedProduct.title,
                              description: _editedProduct.description,
                              price: _editedProduct.price,
                              imageUrl: value.toString());
                        },
                        onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                          _submitForm();
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/isEmpty.html - it is a property, not method

Comment: @jamesdlin when I use isEmpty I get these error   {

 "message": "Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.\nTry changing the condition.",
 "

Comment: Sigh, I meant just remove the parentheses.  For example, `value!.isEmpty`.

Answer (score 1):

isEmpty is a property, not method. remove the parentheses, `value!.isEmpty`

for example

```
 validator: (value) {
  if (value!.isEmpty) { // Do not use value!.isEmpty()
    return " Provide the tile";
  }
```

Comment: actually you did not remove `()`

Comment: In the comment next to the wrong code, I put the correct code

Comment: if you say: *"remove the parentheses, for example"* and then you show the code with parentheses it makes little sense

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I changed the example to avoid mistakes